# cannot delete application on Lion

Tags: launchpad, macos, applications

I cannot delete remove applications on Lion.

When I delete some application in launchpad it disappear and reappear.

Situations are quite the same as in this clip( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbh-jUgCjs0 ) I found.

I could delete applications and I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

First, you can't delete applications from Launchpad. You need to delete them from Applications.

Second, you can't delete some system applications (that are essential part of OS X) from Applications by dragging them to Trash. You can only delete applications that you've added. (Actually you can delete system applications, but not by dragging to Trash; it requires some command line interface usage).

Comment: hold your mouse on an application in launch pad, you can do it.

Comment: That works only for apps installed through App Store doesn't delete the the applications for good, but just from Launchpad; it seems that the OP wants to delete them for good. If what is needed is to remove them from Launchpad only: http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/05/remove-apps-from-launchpad/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AppDelete` This will actually make sure no files are left from the application.

http://www.reggieashworth.com/appdelete

Or use the Lite version of AppDelete.

Or you can also try MacKeeper, using the uninstall option - it does the same, removing all left over files from the application. There's a free trial so you can try it out.

http://mackeeper.zeobit.com/

Comment: I use AppCleaner myself. No cost associated with it, does a great job. I wouldn't use it on apps installed via AppStore though - for that, I'd use the hover method in Launchpad.